# Выравнивание кода в sublime

Tags: sublime-text

Был у меня плагин для выравнивания, но забыл название. Активировался при сочетании ctr + shift + d.
В скаченном проекте весь css файл в одну строку.
Поделитесь какие плагины вы знаете для этого  ( alignment не помогает и edit > line тоже)

Comment: Для чего вам это? Если вы хотите сжать код, то нужно использовать компрессор (он же обфускатор), а не записывать в одну строку.

Answer (score 1):

```
Preferences -> Key Bindings
```

И в поле справа:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false } }
]
```